# confusing error in Vue event Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.$auth.getAccessToken(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

To prefeace this, I'm a novice at JS programming, I'm a .net guy, so this may be the source of the cofusion.

On my PageLayout.vue, in the created event, I'm trying to do authentication stuff (using okta)

The error I'm getting is:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.$auth.getAccessToken(...).then is not a function
at eval (PageLayout.vue?66f1:87)

but right above the call to getAccessToken, the call to this.$auth.GetUser() is a success, we are literally in the then call of that method.

Does the this change scope in the then call?

Then why does this.$store.commit('SET_OKTA_USER', user) succeed right before it?

```
created() {
    this.$store.commit('SET_LOADING_APP', true)

    this.$auth.getUser().then((user) => {
      // Set Okta user
      if (user == null && user == undefined) {

        // no user
        this.$store.commit(
          'SET_RESPONSE_MSG',
          'Okta user is null or undefined.'
        )
        this.$store.commit('SET_RESPONSE_TYPE', 'error')
      } else {
        // store user
        this.$store.commit('SET_OKTA_USER', user)

        // store token
        this.$auth.getAccessToken().then((token) => { //<---------blow up here saying it's not a function.
          this.$store.commit('SET_ACCESS_TOKEN', token)
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token))
          apiClient.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
        })
        // adName
        const adName = user.preferred_username.substr(
          0,
          user.preferred_username.indexOf('@')
        )
        this.$store.commit('SET_AD_NAME', adName)
        this.getUserInfo(adName)
      }
    })
  },
```

I'm at a loss as to why the code above it is valid, but the getAccessToken is not.

ifi paste

```
  const accessToken = this.$auth.getAccessToken();
  if (accessToken != undefined)
  {
      this.setUserToken(accessToken);
      this.getUserInfo(this.$store.state.adName);
  }
```

Immediately above the this.$auth.getAccessToken().then... it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I feel pretty confident that this is a variable scope issue, but I'm not entirely sure how to describe it.

Basically the anonymous function that's being passed to `then` is creating a new private scope,

```
this.$auth.getUser().then((user)=>{
  //this no longer exists like you expect it to
});
```

The simplest solution that occurs to me would be to change your `created()` method to async so that you can rework it to something like this:

```
async created(){
  let user = await this.$auth.getUser();
  //do some stuff
  let token = await this.$auth.getAccessToken(); 
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but if so, then how does const accessToken = this.$auth.getAccessToken(); work? (no promise)

Comment: `this.$auth.getAccessToken` is still a promise, you're just calling it differently. You can call promises like `promise().then().catch()`, or `let res try{ res= await promise(); }catch(err){console.error(err)}`